# How can I generate all possible melody strings for this melody generator, minus the duplicates offset by some number of beats?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have this question on [the *Mathematics* site](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to figure out how to calculate the number of combinations of melodies in this situation: *[How many patterns can be built from sequences of these musical notes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4648581/how-many-patterns-can-be-built-from-sequences-of-these-musical-notes)*

How would you generate all possible strings of melodies, where a melody can be from 3 to 11 beats long, and contain 1 to 12 notes?

Some example melodies would be:

```
[4/4 beat]
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 ...
[5/4 beat]
1 2 1 2 3 1 2 1 2 3 ...
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4 5 6 ...
...
```

It can't repeat beats which are simply offset by some number of beats, like these are:

```
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 ...
2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 ...
3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
...
```

How would you generate an algorithm which was like this:

```
function getMelodies(numBeats, numNotes) {
  // 1. somehow get every combination of 4 notes
  // 2. and then shuffle each combination to get all variants
  // 3. and filter out ones offset by some number of beats
}
```

I start to get lost right off the bat:

```
function getMelodies(beats, notes) {
  let array = []
  let i = 0
  while (i < notes) {
    array.push([i, i, i, i])
    array.push([i, i + 1, i + 1, i + 1]);
    array.push([i, i + 2, i + 2, i + 2]);
  }
}
```

So according to the *Mathematics* question, a 4-beat 7-note melody will have 616 possibilities, if that's of any help.

Comment: There's a catch on your question that the answer you saw in math exchange doesn't include... you're looking for different sizes of "necklaces" in addition for different sizes of kind of "beads" which means you have duplication which can't be counted regularly. for example: {1,2,3} with size 3 will be the same as {1,2,3,1,2,3} with size 6... the answer is strict for 4 beat on 7 notes and not **up to** 4 beat on 7 notes.. remember also that can be necklaces which can't be made with larger sizes, like {1,2,3} sequence can't be replicated with offset with sequence in size 4... anyway it's tricky

Comment: As you've written the question it has quite a high requirement for the answerers to be music SMEs to understand it. Can you reword it a bit so that it is more clear what you are asking to people who aren't SMEs? I feel that this might be a problem applicable in other places as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, two melodies are considered to be duplicates of each other if one can be transformed into the other by applying a rotation.

You could define a melody to be a "principal" melody if among its duplicates it is the one ordered first in a lexical ordering. So for instance, take this melody:

```
1 2 0 2 0 2 1 0
```

The lexical ordering of the set of duplicates would be:

```
0 1 2 0 2 0 2 1
0 2 0 2 1 0 1 2
0 2 1 0 1 2 0 2
1 0 1 2 0 2 0 2
1 2 0 2 0 2 1 0
2 0 2 0 2 1 0 1
2 0 2 1 0 1 2 0
2 1 0 1 2 0 2 0
```

And so the principal is `0 1 2 0 2 0 2 1`.

Then we could aim for an algorithm that only produces principals. To achieve this we should detect if after having generated a few notes (a partial melody) we reproduce the *first* note. If so, the note that comes after it should not be "less" than the second note of the partial melody. If we select the same note as the second note, then for the note that comes after *that* we should check against the third note. And so on... If we select a greater note, then we "reset" the check to start at the first note of the partial melody again.

Special care is to be taken when we have produced a complete melody. If that melody was still in a reproducing phase, where the repeated partial melody is relatively small, we might still not want to produce it. Take this example:

```
1 2 3 4 1 2 3
```

Here we would have tracked that the final `1 2 3` was matching the start of the melody and that if we would have needed an additional note, it should be at least a 4. But as the melody is complete, we should consider that this is not a principal melody, as `1 2 3 1 2 3 4` is the principal among the duplicates. We should reject a finished melody when it has repeated a part that is less than half the melody length -- which is the case in this example.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript:

```js
function getMelodies(beats, notes) {
    // Generator (could also be a normal function that pushes to a non-local array)
    function* recur(melody, reusedCount) {
        if (melody.length === beats) {
            if (reusedCount === 0 || reusedCount * 2 >= beats) yield melody; 
            return;
        }
        let least = melody[reusedCount] ?? -1;
        if (melody.length) yield* recur(melody.concat(least), reusedCount + 1);
        for (let note = least + 1; note < notes; note++) {
            yield* recur(melody.concat(note), note === melody[0] ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }

    return Array.from(recur([], 0));
}

// Example run
const beats = 4, notes = 7;
const melodies = getMelodies(beats, notes);
console.log("Melodies:"); 
// Be aware that Stack Snippet console only retains the last 50 lines of output!
for (const melody of melodies) console.log(...melody);
console.log("total count", melodies.length); // 616
```

Without generator:

```js
function getMelodies(beats, notes) {
    const melodies = [];
    
    function recur(melody, reusedCount) {
        if (melody.length === beats) {
            if (reusedCount === 0 || reusedCount * 2 >= beats) melodies.push(melody); 
            return;
        }
        let least = melody[reusedCount] ?? -1;
        if (melody.length) recur(melody.concat(least), reusedCount + 1);
        for (let note = least + 1; note < notes; note++) {
            recur(melody.concat(note), note === melody[0] ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }

    recur([], 0);
    return melodies;
}

// Example run
const beats = 4, notes = 7;
const melodies = getMelodies(beats, notes);
console.log("Melodies:"); 
// Be aware that Stack Snippet console only retains the last 50 lines of output!
for (const melody of melodies) console.log(...melody);
console.log("total count", melodies.length); // 616
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without generators? I am getting this in TypeScript: "Type 'IterableIterator<number[]>' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher."