# How can I get all k-length combinations of an n-length array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have this question, *[How can I generate all possible melody strings for this melody generator, minus the duplicates offset by some number of beats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75598430/how-to-generate-all-possible-melody-strings-for-this-melody-generator-minus-the)*, but perhaps it can be simplified into subproblems, such as this current question.

Here, I am wondering how to take an array of length `n` and find all combinations of `k` number of elements.

So for example, you have an array like this:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]
```

And you want to find all combinations of length-4 subarrays which would be something like this:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
...
[ 1, 2, 4, 5 ]
...
[ 1, 2, 3, 6 ]
```

How would you do that in JavaScript? I get lost right away:

```
function getCombinations(k, n) {
  const array = new Array(n)
  array.forEach((x, i) => {
    array[i] = i + 1
  })
  const results = []
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      let l = k
      const result = []
      while (l--) {
        result.push(j) // ???
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest splitting the logic for *creating* the array from getting *combinations* from it into two different functions.

For getting combinations, you might want to consider using a generator function:

```js
const sequence = (length) => Array.from({length}, (_, i) => i + 1); 

function* getCombinations(array, k, taken=[]) {
    if (k == 0) return yield taken;
    if (array.length < k) return;
    yield* getCombinations(array.slice(1), k - 1, taken.concat(array[0]));
    yield* getCombinations(array.slice(1), k, taken);
}

const combis = [...getCombinations(sequence(6), 4)];

console.log(combis);
```